# Is submitting username & password plaintext in POST payload over HTTPS connection secure enough?

Tags: security, https

Not a security expert so bear with me.

In this application for the login page (called login.do) I see username and password being submitted in a form POST payload in plaintext but over an HTTPS connection. Is this secure enough? Or should the username and password be hashed or encrypted in the 'Authorization' header here even though it's HTTPS?

I've read that in the case of HTTP it should be hashed or encrypted in the 'Authorization' header, but not sure if that still applies for HTTPS?

Comment: While the duplicated question has the PHP tag, this matter is more about HTTPs and client-server security rather than specific to Java (or any other programming language).
Also, adding an additional encryption won't help because this code will be executed on the client. This means that any person with enough knowledge can see how to encrypt/decrypt the data from the client code itself.